# how to replace same words in javascript multiple times?

Tags: javascript, replace

Our developer used this phone number `1-866-579-469` all over the website but the correct phone number is `1-866-579-4269`. I have written a javascript function to replace all occurrences:

```
var nodes,currentElement,oldtext,newtext,replaced,count;
function replaceAll(nodes,oldtext,newtext,replaced) { 
    count = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    currentElement  = nodes[i].innerHTML;  
    replaced = currentElement.replace(oldtext,newtext);
    count++;
  }
  console.log("Edited: "+ count + " items");
}

oldtext = "1-866-579-469";
newtext = "1-866-579-4269";
nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

replaceAll(nodes,oldtext,newtext,replaced);
```

Comment: if counting items is not critical, the replacement can be done in a much shorter way

Comment: Can you please tell me that way?

Comment: I could post an answer, but you already had one

Comment: what is the shorter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works but you missed to update the replaced string. This should work:

```
var nodes,currentElement,oldtext,newtext,replaced,count;
function replaceAll(nodes,oldtext,newtext,replaced) { 
    count = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    currentElement  = nodes[i].innerHTML;  
    replaced = currentElement.replace(oldtext,newtext);
    nodes[i].innerHTML = replaced;
    count++;
  }
  console.log("Edited: "+ count + " items");
}

oldtext = "1-866-579-469";
newtext = "1-866-579-4269";
nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

replaceAll(nodes,oldtext,newtext,replaced);
```

Codepen [Here](http://codepen.io/iksdatoo/pen/XMQQMB?editors=1010)